Add data into single row for same ids
I have table like this.
CREATE TABLE test
(
    courtnum varchar(max),
    casenum int, 
    startdate datetime,
    enddate datetime,
    pocdate datetime, 
    pocenddate datetime
)

INSERT INTO test 
VALUES ('abc', 123, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), NULL, NULL),
       ('abc', 123, NULL, NULL, GETDATE(), GETDATE())

After insert
select * from test 

will show 2 rows - but I need single row, like
Courtnum casenum sd ed psdt pedt
---------------------------------
Abc      123   

I am trying a group by as example I have added four columns but total I have 8 columns
Suppose if court number n case number is same bring a single row instead of individual row.

What is the logic for combining those 2 records into 1 row?

"I am trying a group by as example I have added four columns..."  4 ??  Please show what your did, because your explanation is unclear.

You can use the GROUP BY clause along with aggregate functions like MIN and MAX to consolidate the startdate, enddate, pocdate, and pocenddate into a single row. Here's an example query:
SELECT courtnum,
   casenum,
   MIN(startdate) AS startdate,
   MAX(enddate) AS enddate,
   MIN(pocdate) AS pocdate,
   MAX(pocenddate) AS pocenddate
FROM test
GROUP BY courtnum, casenum;

This query groups the records by courtnum and casenum, and for each group, it calculates the minimum startdate, maximum enddate, minimum pocdate, and maximum pocenddate, effectively consolidating the two rows into one.

Works fine. Thanks

"Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation." so there is no need to mix MIN and MAX, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZGb4iArZ

@Luuk, using MIN for starts and MAX for ends seems more logical. During code review, looking just at the code and not knowing actual data, I'd prefer MIN-MAX
